# Post entry data to html table rows

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, dom

I have a HTML table and I want to create a new row of entered data on submit. Only the date and mileage entries will be rendered to the table, the other columns will be back end calculations.

```js
var miles = $('#miles').value;
var date = $('#date').value;
var mileSubmit = document.getElementById('add-mileage');
mileSubmit.document.addEventListener('click', function(date, miles) {
    document.getElementById('add-mileage').appendChild(
        document.createElement("tr")
    );
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <form class="maintenance">
        <label for="date">Date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="date">

        <label>Enter Current Mileage:</label>
        <input name="mileage" type="number" id="miles">
        
    </form>

    <button id="add-mileage" type="submit" >Submit</button>
</section>

<h2>Mileage LogBook</h2>

<table id="logbook">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Mileage</th>
        <th>column C</th>
        <th>Column D</th>
    </tr>   
</table>

<script src="/javascript/add-mileage.js"></script>
```

Comment: To start with, you need to appendChild to the table, not the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

The submit isn't inserting into the table because you don't have any code to insert your data into the table. Right now, your function just tries to fetch data from the server, if that succeeds, it changes the window location to `/logbook`, otherwise it pops up with an error.

Did you mean to manipulate the DOM somehow, like this?

```
const table = document.getElementById("logbook");
const row = table.insertRow(-1);
// etc etc?
```